# cmake : How to change file permissions when installing?

Tags: linux, cmake, file-permissions

I have a file with `660` flags set, but I want to install it with `700` flags set.

How do I do it? How to change the file permission, without changing the permissions of the source file?

---

My install command is this :

```
install(
    FILES common.sh
    DESTINATION /rootfs/usr/bin
)
```

and this is what I tried (but it doesn't work) :

```
install(
    FILES common.sh
    FILE_PERMISSIONS "600"
    DESTINATION /rootfs/usr/bin
)
```

Comment: Take a look to `umask`.

Comment: @fedorqui what do you mean?

Comment: For example http://superuser.com/questions/264383/set-file-permissions-so-that-new-files-inherit-same-permissions

Comment: @fedorqui I know how to set the permisions, but how do you do it when installing using cmake?

Comment: Not familiar with it, just commented based on the first revision on the question. I would suggest saving the current umask, but let's see what other people suggest.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no `FILE_PERMISSIONS` argument in [`install(FILES ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:install).  Use `PERMISSIONS` instead:

```
install(
    FILES common.sh
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ
    DESTINATION /rootfs/usr/bin
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But the page you linked talks about FILE_PERMISSIONS. I just noticed it is not for install(), but the file() command. Would it be possible to set permission using file() command as it seems to provide better control?

Comment: Well, they do different things.  Files added in `install(FILES ...)` are installed when `make install` is executed and are added to any install packages you make.  Files added in `file(INSTALL ...)` are installed when CMake runs, before the build is even started.

Comment: Is this solution cross compatible? I tried it on linux and it worked ,but I want the equivalent in all three major pc OSes