# Cmake not changing permission of file installed

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to change the permission of a file that is installed in Cmake, and it's not working.  I seem to be doing what they discuss at [discussion of permission changing](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2010-February/034965.html) , the permission is just wrong on the file the first time I edit it and it fails to apply the change (then it fixes it's own permission magically for the next time I save it).

```
    configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj.in
                   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj)
    file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj
       DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
       FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
       )
```

I tried doing it like [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399705/cmake-how-to-change-file-permissions-when-installing) but get an error message .... Doing this at install had an error msg saying the file didn't exist, but it was showing the location that the file was supposed to be at. Maybe it wasn't installed at that point yet.

Comment: I am unsure that `file(COPY)` can change file's permissions **in place**, as you want. Note, that the discussion you refer to uses `${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}` as appendix for configured file's directory, so `file(COPY)` **actually copies** the file.

Comment: But it's supposed to give different permission when it copies the file.   For me the permission isn't changing until after I try to save the file the first time.

Comment: Again, `file(COPY)` is supposed to work only when destination file **differs** from source one. You want this command to replace permissions "at place", when destination and source are the *same file*.

Comment: How would you recommend changing the permission of that file then?

Comment: As your reference suggests, `configure_file` **into some other dir**, and then `file(COPY)` it into desirable location. In that case setting permissions should work.

Comment: It works!  I didn't realize the new dir part was that important!  It's working now!  I configured it to a temp location and then copied it with permissions to the correct location and it's right now.  Thanks @Tsyvarev!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev discussions, we determined that the configure had to put the file in a different location than the copy was getting it from for the permissions change to work so I added a temp dir:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj.in
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/temp/${PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj)
    file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/temp/${PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
       FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
       )
```