# CMake install file permissions are not the correct permissions

Tags: cmake, debian

I am using CMake to make a Debian package and I am installing a file which I need to edit (aka have write permissions)

I tried using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399705/cmake-how-to-change-file-permissions-when-installing), and it does not work for me.

I also tried looking in the [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:install) and there was no help there.

```
install(FILES 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileA 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fileB
    DESTINATION /etc/path/here
    PERMISSIONS
    OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ
    GROUP_EXECUTE GROUP_WRITE GROUP_READ
    WORLD_EXECUTE WORLD_WRITE WORLD_READ
    )
```

When I install the Debian package, it puts the file in the proper location but not with the permissions I specified. It give the permissions of -rwxr-xr-x when I am looking for -rwxrwxrwx.

Comment: "When I install the Debian package.." - So you actually created `.deb` package with CPack, and then installed it into the target machine, didn't you? Have you tried to install the project **without** packaging it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have not. Although in the end I will need to have the .deb package.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you finally need `.deb`. Trying "normal" (without CPack) installing would help to classify the problem between "This is pure CMake bug in the basic installation" and "Something wrong with CPack or its settings". In the latter case it is better to note CPack in the title and in the tags.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Before I run CPack, the permissions are giving me "-rwxr-xr-x" as well